# Autohotkey+IE WB.document.write() works only TWICE, why?

Tags: activex, autohotkey

I'm trying to use IE ActiveX control to update Autohotkey GUI dynamically, but encountering weird behavior. Please help.

```
; ie-refresh.ahk on Autohotkey 1.1.24
global WB

Gui, Font, s9 cBlack, Tahoma
Gui, Add, Text, , % "Click button to see html content."
Gui, Add, ActiveX, xm w120 h30 vWB, Shell.Explorer
Gui, Add, Button, xm gBtnClicked, % "Update html text"
Gui Show
return

BtnClicked()
{
    html_tmpl = 
( Ltrim Join
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
                margin: 0px;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
Count: {}
    </body>
</html>
)
    static snum := 0
    snum++

    html_code := Format(html_tmpl, snum)

    WB.Navigate("about:blank")
    WB.document.write(html_code)

}

GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

When I click the button, the IE content updates, **but it only updates twice**.

[image: IE ActiveX updating]

On third button click, IE content area almost certainly **shows as blank**.

[image]

Keep clicking the button, the red text appears intermittently and randomly, rougly one out of ten clicks.

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with calling navigate the second time.

I thought that WB.Stop() would fix the problem but after that you find out that WB.Navigate is not enough to clean the screen so...

The most sensible alternative looks like putting the WB.Navigate after the gui-add (or somewhere after) and then using WB.Refresh() .

Just for refrerence, some WebBrowser Control documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752043(v%3Dvs.85)).

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot explain the weird behavior in my question, I have managed to find out a solution to my requirement.

Use code below:

```
; ie-refresh.ahk on Autohotkey 1.1.24
global WB

Gui, Font, s9 cBlack, Tahoma
Gui, Add, Text, , % "Click button to see html content."
Gui, Add, ActiveX, xm w120 h30 vWB, Shell.Explorer
Gui, Add, Button, xm gBtnClicked, % "Update html text"
WB.Navigate("about:blank")
Gui Show
return

BtnClicked()
{
    html_tmpl = 
( Ltrim Join
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
                margin: 0px;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
Count: {}
    </body>
</html>
)
    static snum := 0
    snum++

    html_code := Format(html_tmpl, snum)

    WB.document.open()
    WB.document.write(html_code)
    WB.document.close()
}

GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

First, call `WB.navigate("about:blank")` only once.

Second, when I need to update the whole html document, I need to open + write + close.

Now it works reliably.